# Allocating big space in C++ OS X

Tags: c++, macos, exception

I'm learning exceptions in C++ and I was trying this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    double *p_x;
    try {
        p_x = new double[100000000000000];
        delete p_x;
    } catch (bad_alloc& ex) {
        cout << "Memory not allocated !!\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The exception gets caught but there's other stuff printed when executing this code. The output looks like:

```
Memory not allocated !!
Test9(13814) malloc: *** mmap(size=800000000000000) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I don't know if it's somehow related to the version of g++ or maybe related to the OS X.
I mean, the program is catching the exception but what is the other stuff about?

Comment: It's just a debug message from new/malloc. Note that `delete p_x` should be `delete [] p_x`.

Comment: If you build your code in release mode you won't see this.

Comment: @Benj even if I try to build in release mode the message appears. I'm working with Eclipse.

Comment: It has nothing to do with debug or release mode, use mallopt as mentioned in my answer. With this function you can also disable the messy stacktraces produced by a segfaulting application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's glibc related. You can disable these messages with the `mallopt(3)` command:

```
mallopt(M_CHECK_ACTION, 0);
```

Comment: Where should I put that line? do I need to include some library? ... I searched for the `man` entry but I get `No manual entry for mallopt`

Comment: [mallopt(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallopt.3.html) Just call this function in your application's main routine. It's part of the `glibc`

Comment: That's the error that appears when I try to compile `../Tests.cpp:32: error: 'mallopt' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [Tests.o] Error 1`

Comment: Yep actually I tried it but got this `Tests.cpp:13:20: warning: malloc.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: Hmm, I don't know anything about OSX, but on Ubuntu Linux the header is in the `libc6-dev` package. Perhaps you must install additional packages (also for the manpage).

Comment: Yep I found the header file it was under /usr/include/sys now the message doesn't show ! thanks :)

Comment: Should we disable these messages though?  Do they signal errors in our code?